# My Firebase notification service only work with Debugger in Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing and android applications that implement a firebase notification service
as developing proccess i work with debugger in all the working flow but i just realize than
when i run the application with the "run" button instead of debug button or i install the apk
in a device, the notification are not received.

All the research about the notification service dont explaind nothing about this problem
on android, only on IOS.

I check the configuration of the pushlauncher application, the token, the notice's id. But i dont know if is need any aditional setting in google cloud.

Comment: How are you testing this? Is it using the same FCM token obtained for the debug version?

Comment: When the App is installed, it generate and store the FCM token in a DB with an id from the device. so ever I use that token until it needs to be renewed.