# XAMARIN Android - IN-APP notifications not working in RELEASE mode with Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging

Tags: android, xamarin.android, notifications

I have an Android application with Xamarin and I use FirebaseMessaging to receive notifications. I receive notifications when the app is closed, and I receive notifications in app, when the app is open.

When my app is running in **DEBUG mode**, *everything  is working*, I get notifications fine.

But, when my app is running in **RELEASE mode**, or if I use the **APK** of my application, the *notifications IN APP only no longer work...* But they still work if the app is closed.

Here the code to *get the token *:

```
     public string GetToken()
        {
            string token = CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.Token;
          
            return token;
        }
```

Here the code *to receive notifications when the app is running :
*

```
[Service(Exported = false)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
    public class FirebaseService : FirebaseMessagingService
    {

        public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            //Log.Debug(TAG, "Venant de: " + message.From);
            //Log.Debug(TAG, "Contenu de la notif: " + message.GetNotification().Body);

            if (message.GetNotification() != null)
            {
                long longDate = message.SentTime;
                DateTime start = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                DateTime dateTimeNotif = start.AddMilliseconds(longDate).ToLocalTime();

                EventCatch newNotif = new EventCatch
                {
                    Id_Client = AccesData.clientCourant.Id_Client,
                    Id_Compte = AccesData.compteCourant.Id_Compte,
                    NotifTitle = message.GetNotification().Title,
                    NotifBody = message.GetNotification().Body,
                    Lu = false,
                    NotifDateHeureEnvoi = dateTimeNotif,
                };

                AccesData accesData = new AccesData();
                accesData.SauvEventLocal(newNotif);

                accesData.OnNewEvent(newNotif);
            }
        }
}
```

Here the code of the event to *catch the body of the notification*, **when app IS RUNNING,** and show it to the user :

```
  public void OnNewEvent(EventCatch eventCatch)
        {
            RecupNotif?.Invoke(eventCatch, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
```

And the *delegate*, in the code behind of my XAML Page:

```
 AccesData.RecupNotif += ShowNewNotification;
```

The *function *(when notification is received, I have a bell that turns red in the navigation bar) :

```
  private void ShowNewNotification(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //frameNotif.IsVisible = true;
            btnAlertNotif.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
        }
```

In the **DEBUG MODE**, everything is working, I receive all the notifications, *in the application, and also when the app is closed.*

But  in **RELEASE mode**, only *the IN-APP notification* dont't work, with the **APK**, or in **PRODUCTION**...

I can't understand why ? I've been stuck on it for over a month.

[it seems that this unanswered question is similar to my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75080572/my-firebase-notification-service-only-work-with-debugger-in-android)

Any ideas ? Thanks for help.

**EDIT :**

I have also :

- generate my *SHA-1 key*
- Add my SHA-1 to firebase console
- download the new *google-services.json*
- add I added it in my application

**But the notifications IN-APP still don't work...**

[image: My certificates]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to find where all my problem came from.

I was actually using two packages to use the notifications in my application.

The first was **Plugin.FirebasePushNotification**, with which *I generated my token and initialized the service on app launch.*

And the second was **Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging**, with which I was *getting the notifications messages*, but also *initializing the service with it*, in my MainActivity.

So I removed everything from **Plugin.FirebasePushNotification** in order to only use **Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging**.

And now it works wonderfully...

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Does your google-services json contain an additional SHA certificate fingerprint for your release build?

Comment: I don't need no additional SHA certificate fingerprint ? The application is already signed by google certificate and validated by the PlayStore.

Answer (score 0):

You can first recheck if you have added your SHA-1 key of signature for the release to your firebase console.

For released version, there is a different SHA-1 key .

You can try the following steps:

- Generate your `SHA-1` for release
- Add your release `SHA-1` to firebase console
- Download and use new `google-services.json`.

**Note:** Make sure the key being used by play store to sign your releases is
also added in step 2

There are some similar threads about this problem,you can check them here:

[FCM notifications not working in release app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65488046/fcm-notifications-not-working-in-release-app)

[Firebase google authentication not working in release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48439480/firebase-google-authentication-not-working-in-release-mode)

Comment: thx for your answer. I did what you said, but I still don't get notifcations in-app. I edited my question with the new information. Do you have any other ideas of what i might be missing? ?

Comment: Have you used `proguard` or set `Linker` to `SDK Assemblies Only` or `Sdk and User Assemblies` in release mode?